# Save response from certain WEB resources while recording scenario

Tags: jmeter

I need to create scenario for user interaction with single-page WEB application. The application does lots of AJAX calls in order to authenticate user and get user data.

So I created simple scenario with **HTTP Test Script Recorder** and tried to record my script.

Everything went well, however I noticed that whilst request data is recorder properly, the response data is not recorder at all. I tried to enable **Add assertions** and **Regex matching** - but that didn't work as well.

Can you please advice how do I record response texts as well?

Comment: HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder does not record responses. If you want it for debugging just add `View Results Tree` listener when running the test.

Comment: Any feedback on this ? if response is OK , you should accept it if not please comment

Answer (score 1):

View Results Tree under proxy will record request, responses during recording.

This is useful to understand where a dynamic field comes from. This will help your find from which response X you need to extract data to inject in request X+N.

I think you may find this option useful to add in user.properties:

- proxy.number.requests=true

This will give a number to each request and corresponding sampler so you will be able to find response for the request.

Once you have done this, you will start adding Post Processors (Regex, CSS/JQuery, XPAth ...) to Sampler X to extract data from its response.
This will create variables you can then use as ${varName} in request X+N.

Comment: It doesn't really help, because I can't easily match corresponding request and response. It would be great if HTTP sampler will record response in place somehow.

Comment: You can match as sampler name will be the same as request in view tree results

Comment: I have lots of requests to the same URL, so the name of sampler will be the same all time.

Comment: No because with the option I gave you, they will be preceded by a number 1-XXXXX, 2-XXXXX. Believe me and try it.

Comment: it's hard to associate > 100 requests in such way.